# Show reCaptcha from third-party site

Tags: android, recaptcha

So I want my app to scrape some data from various sites, and one of them shows a recaptcha.

I was able to detect it in my app but I'm having problems figuring out a way to show the captcha to the user. The site is loaded in background with AndroidHttpClient.

I did some research and found nothing that could help me accomplish this for a third party site. The captcha needs to be solved and my quasi-browser (the androidhttpclient which just loads a bunch of sites in background) needs to get access to the site to gather the needed data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar project and I used a bitmap to capture the image (captcha) e show to the user in Android.

```
public Bitmap getCodigoCaptcha(String src){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        return myBitmap;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I get this bitmap from the url that I need and set a ImageView in Android to show to the user.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a TSimpleCaptcha or JCaptcha?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but these are captcha generators, but I do not own or control the site that's using the captcha. The site redirects to the page where you have to fill the recaptcha, and I need to show that to the user so he can fill it out and my "quasi-browser" can continue.